# How to set TempData in <script> tag in cshtml

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to set a `TempData` in `cshtml` inside the `<script>` tag. Following is my code.

```
$("#btnGetResult").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var JSONString = JSON.stringify($("#JSONString").val());
        '@TempData["JSON"]' = $("#JSONString").val();
```

The error I am getting is

```
 Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

What I am doign wrong in setting `TempData["JSON"]` as I have to use this tempdata in my controller.

This is my code  in which `put` is a div and I am trying to load the partial view. When I pass the JSONSTRING, I get the whole JSONSTRING in js but only `[{` is passed to controller. Rest all is skiped.

```
_OutPut is the partial view

$("#put").load('@Url.Action("_OutPut", "API")'+
'?UD=' + $("#UD").val() +
'&JSONString=' + JSONString
);
```

Comment: You should post the JSON string to an action method instead of using TempData if at all possible. TempData should not be changed by the view.

Comment: @br4d.net : I tried. The JSON string is too long. When I post it directly only the [{ of the JSON is pased. Rest all the huge JSON is skipped.

Comment: `TempData` is for passing data between requests in the controller. You usage make no sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You *cannot* do that through javascript.

Comment: @ShaunakD and stephen : Please see my above comment.

Comment: Can you post your code of your attempt to post it directly? Sounds like you were just sending the wrong data

Comment: `TempData` is a c# class. The browser/javascript has no concept of what `TempaData` is. And razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. You cant set a server side object to a value in the client when the client does not even exist yet

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you could change the action method handling the _Output partial to be HTTP Post instead of GET to avoid the JSON being too long or posting illegal characters (IIS default max is 4096). If its not posting the full JSON then, you need to check out the value of "#JSONString" element to see if it has good data in it.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOutputPartial(string UD, string JSONString)
{
    // youll need to deserialize JSONString here most likely

    // return PartialView just like you were doing before
}
```

Javascript in view:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetOutputPartial", "CONTROLLERNAME")",
    data: { ud: $("#UD").val(), JSONString: $("#JSONString").val() },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        $("#put").html(data);
    }
});
```

or you can use jquery's load if you like as it POSTs if you give it an object:

```
$("#put").load('@Url.Action("GetOutputPartial", "CONTROLLERNAME")', { ud: $("#UD").val(), JSONString: $("#JSONString").val() });
```